# Manipulation of Composition of Functions

Tags: proof-verification, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f: A\to B$ and $g,g' : B \to C$.  Prove that if $g \circ f=g' \circ f$ and $f$ is surjective then $g=g'$.

Is it fair to say that since $f$ is surjective it has a right inverse such that 
$f\circ f^{-1}= \text{Id}_B$
and thus 
$$ g\circ f\circ f^{-1}=g'\circ f\circ f^{-1} $$
which implies $g \circ (\text{Id}_B) = g'\circ (\text{Id}_B)$ and thus $g=g'$?

Comment: For future math-formatting concerns, check [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof by contrapositive:**

Suppose that $g \neq g'$ and that $f$ is surjective (we want to conclude $g \circ f \neq g' \circ f$).

There exists an element $b \in B$ such that $g(b) \neq g'(b)$.  Because $f$ is surjective, there exists an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

Because $g(f(a)) \neq g'(f(a))$, we conclude that $g \circ f \neq g' \circ f$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense.  So for the injective version would you follow the same sort of logic but say since h(a)=h(a') implies a=a'it must be true that hog does not equal hog' since h(g) does not equal h(g') since h is injective?

Comment: And if f wasn't surjective and h wasn't injective would you simply be unable to tell if these statements were true?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the argument you've presented is valid.

Comment: Thank you can I apply similar logic for the question of fog=fog' and f is injective?  I would say that since f is injective it has a left inverse such that f^-1 o f = Id_A and then plug in f^-1 in front of both f's in the initial equality?

Comment: That's correct.  This, of course, assumes that in the class you're proving this for, you've established that injective/surjective functions have left/right inverses (respectively).

Comment: If we haven't covered those (I learned it on my own) would you suggest I prove them in the question or answer with another method?

Comment: I would think that the grader might take issue with this approach if this way of considering surjections wasn't covered.  Perhaps you should prove that such an $f^{-1}$ exists by constructing it.

Comment: Hmmh....Is there a way to construct it without the axiom of choice?  That is what I used when teaching myself left and right inverses

Comment: @Trevor that... is a fair point.  I would use the axiom of choice.  In fact, I think that the axiom of choice may be necessary to prove  this statement, even with a direct approach.

Comment: @Trevor for good measure, try a direct proof of the contrapositive.  I'm trying to decide whether that needs the axiom of choice at some point.

Comment: @Trevor yes.  At any rate, it's probably a good exercise to use some sort of element-wise argument for these.  Remember that $g = g'$ iff $g(x) = g'(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: The contrapositive would be if g is not equal to g' then gof is not equal to g'of or f is not surjective, correct?  I'm not terribly sure where I would go from here, I feel like it is already proven then.  Since if f is applied to a domain and then g and g' are different then they can't be equal which proves the "or" statement correct.